What species would make good flying livestock?
Domesticated magpies will carefully watch over these flying livestock like smarter, louder, sheepdogs, driving away would be predators (along with the help of a much smaller number of domesticated eagles, falcons, etc). Without any human contact for up to months at a time these magpies will herd the livestock birds between regions, filling an analogous role to cowboys.
Though early cities and their surrounding farmland are far more dense/efficient than normal for the tech level (for reasons beyond the scope of this question). So you will also have livestock birds which nest in a set location, and feed off the surrounding wilderness, or use a nesting wagon/sled pulled by animals often with little human involvement.
This is a technologically primitive civilization which figured out mendelian genetics way earlier, but takes hundreds of thousands of years to start building cities. So there's a lot of time for selective breeding to do its work. The timeline of this setting also means you can consider as potential domestication targets species from up to the last half million years.
The proposed species need to be at minimum fast growing, flocking, and tasty. They should be able to be herded between feeding spots like free range grazing cattle. Ideally this means you can exploit good grazing/browsing spots that are in rough terrain and/or very far away from the nearest settlement. Being too helpless is also a downside, because while the magpies can be very loud and frightening, they can't keep a constant eye on every bird at once.
I've considered birds like peking ducks, and passenger pigeons as good candidates, but there's probably other good candidates I'm not thinking of, as well as factors I'm not considering. Still if I'm not mistaken, passenger pigeons seem like a particularly good candidate, because they would turn borderline inedible acorns into bird meat and/or eggs.
I also don't know how dramatically it changes things when you have domesticated birds that are herded around like this. Since the birds in question need to maintain their flight, until they're brought back to a settlement and being fattened up for slaughter (like grazing cattle).
Wild birds are still herded into nets and eaten, but I imagine the livestock birds probably taste better and aren't as seasonal. Also over time I'd expect that like with RL grazing livestock these domestic birds may to some extent displace wild birds in the same niche.

Have you looked into domestication of rock doves? AKA pigeons?

The biggest challenge see is the herding birds, the magpies. For sheep dogs humans took advantage of pack based hunting wolves. I don't recall magpies being pack based hunters. I mean if you are invoking magic/rule of cool sure. But why would these magpies with low human contact heard for humans?

Why would you need to herd something to new 'pastures' that will go find the feeding spots itself and then fly home each evening? aka Pigeons, that we've kept for a very long time .. you seem to be inventing problems for yourself that don't actually exist? maybe have a read about Dovecots they didn't need herding or penning, traditional dovecots were often built for them to pretty much come and go at will, a little grain of an evening would bring them in.

what about swans and geese which are already domestcated?

@GaultDrakkor Nearly half a million years of domestication has really done a number on the magpies. While they're not human-level intelligence they are far more patient and disciplined than a human, while having the same overwhelming desire to please as some dogs

@John How would the domestication of those birds change when you can graze them (potentially literally since some of them eat grass) really far away from settlements?

@Pelinore Something like dovecotes will exist, but it seems like the food they could generate would be limited by how many pigeons can be sustained by the wilderness around that dovecot. In the same way that cows grazing on pasture fill a different niche than cows grazed on more marginal land. Also I don't know if it matters here that edible plant tumors created through infection with a special disease are vastly more prevalent than labor intensive crops like cereal.

Is there a reason the humble chicken isn't suitable? Modern chickens have limited flight mainly due to being overbred for size. The original junglefowl is perfectly capable of flight for short distances, which would improve with selective breeding

@Chromane While chickens would fill their own role, I am interested in birds capable of sustained flight. Since a bird with more mobility can be grazed over a wider area further away from settlements. Since I'm trying to imagine a bird comparison to free range cattle.

Does the cattle-bird have to fly? I'm thinking Ostrich. We're all thinking it. Admit it. And the Magpies are a great way to heard them around.

Magpies aren't big enough to herd anything but the smallest birds. Try ravens. They're really big corvids (same family as magpies) and can mimic human speech as well as being smart. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AfsnHVaScjg What he gets wrong is important as what he gets right: ("Hi" vs "Hello" - I'm sure he knows there's not much  difference in meaning.)

The best flying livestock is one that has its wings cut.

Christmas is coming and the Goose is getting fat....
Please put a penny in the old man's hat.
If you haven't got a penny, then a ha'penny will do.
If you haven't got a ha'penny, then God bless you!
They form small groups for individual households to look after. Half a dozen or fewer geese, lead by a single Gander. (Usually)
Larger flocks may be held by villages, but again, only one gander, or there'll be trouble.
If raised from hatching, the birds will bond to anything that moves. This has been clearly demonstrated in the famous video (excerpt) by Christian Moullec. (The BBC made a documentary some years ago, but I can't find it offhand.) What he does is (apart from giving flights to journalists) periodically migrate the birds to fresh pastureland for them to graze.
At 6 months, a chick is ready for the oven, but they can be kept longer if necessary; the meat is tougher, more sinewy.
They are capable of migration intercontinentally, so satisfy the long-distance flight requirement.
Diet should be varied: grasses, clover, alfalfa, seed heads, wheat, maize, barley, and beans with some berries thrown in when in season. Given wild grassland, they will fend for much of their diet, just add a seasonal supplement of grains for bulk. Bring them into a pen at night with water for bathing etc.. They will endure icy winters if housed with straw and shelter.
Egg production is not as fast as highly-bred chickens, but the eggs themselves are much larger  and quite delicious (personal experience, we had a small flock in my early days).
Perhaps surprisingly, they make great guard-animals, creating a huge barrage of honking and hissing at the sight of an intruder. Persistent intruders will get a nasty peck from serrated beaks, enough to draw blood.
Get them inured to family dogs from an early age - these will protect them from predation.

I definitely didn't expect that you could pull something like this off in RL, very interesting video +1

+1 because geese are better fliers than chickens, and for reminding me of my elementary school days (the title).

the only issue is, the question assumed magpies or similar birds would be used to control flocks of the "livestock" birds. With Geese this is entirely unecessary and largely pointless. A goose will not be cowed into submission by a magpie, and the magpie would not live long trying to force a goose to do something. Moreover, a flock of geese can protect themselves just fine from anything less dangerous than a bear, and can be trained to "shepherd" themselves anyway. So your answer is kinda too good.

It doesn't require that they be cowed into submission. "If raised from hatching, the birds will bond to anything that moves." This refers to the process of imprinting. I've just noticed the Wikipedia page has a picture of canada geese imprinted on someone with an ultralight aircraft, coincidences! @GoingDurden Anyhow I was certain that the geese imprinting on magpies would work. The pies could be trained to feed/water and shepherd them without much trouble.

For a moment I forgot that geese have serrated beaks. Oh well; I suppose they do make better guard dogs than guard dogs into at case.

@controlgroup: I'd still recommend a (big) dog to deter larger predators, and avoid losing geese, but as alarms go geese are really good, just ask the Romans.

Lots of good answers here. One thing to add: the question of "which existing bird is a good fit for this scenario" may be almost irrelevant given the sheer time scale you've had to breed and domesticate them. Artificial selection can happen way faster than natural selection. You've already used that to your advantage with the Magpies. It's impossible to say for certain whether or not breeding Magpies to have dog-like intelligence and personalities is doable, but if so, then it's almost certainly possible to optimize just about whatever bird you want to be livestock.
Take chickens for example, which diverged from their wild ancestor (junglefowl) about 8,000 years ago. There's still a visual resemblance between the two, but we've conveniently made chickens much meatier, tamer, and less inclined to fly away than their ancestors. Better still, they lay more eggs and reach full size much faster. We accomplished that in 8,000 years. You've got half a million years to play with!
What birds did the people in your world choose to use as their livestocK? Probably whatever was plentiful and huntable at the time. Geese, ducks, pigeons, junglefowl, or any number of others will probably do. The specific attributes of the bird in question aren't a huge deal; your people will just change them.

I guess this comes down to how quickly you can select livestock to be able to digest new food sources. Though remembering that cecal valves can evolve really quickly in lizards (https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2008/04/080417112433.htm) makes me think that even that isn't an exception to your point. I now wonder just how over the top things will get with structural colors: since that can be bred into butterflies within a year :p https://www.pnas.org/doi/full/10.1073/pnas.1402770111

Since you insist on magpies being able to "shepherd" the livestock birds effectively,this limits our options. Most birds that would make good livestock are not going to be cowed into submission by a magpie, no matter how smart it was.
Shepherd dogs works well herding sheep, because sheep are very docile, easily scared, and the dog can "motivate" sheep with nonthreatening but painful bites.
A Magpie, crow, or another corvid, has no way of forcing geese, ducks, or even any other fat kind of poultry to do anything. It can alert the human shepherd, but so can geese themselves.
Rather than have actual, semi domesticated "livestock"birds, I would focus on teaching birds of prey to "herd" wild murmurations of flocking birds, like waders.
Waders form gargantuan flocks, that a well trained hawk can keep penned in one general area. Waders feed on abundant marshland critters, so they are very effective at turning biomatter into human food. The same hawk that keeps them from leaving the area, can be used to hunt them.
The only reason why this does not happen in nature, is that bird murmurations confuse hawks and falcons, which cannot deal with the overwhelming sensory input when flying into the murmuration head-on. But a good falconer should be able to train their bird of prey to skim the edges of the murmuration to effectively keep it confined and kill just enough waders to feed the humans without endangering their flock.

I don't know that using these magpies is much different from using drones, which already get used to scare birds including geese: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=2msRG__iL58 Birds have already evolved to produce calls up to 125db, and these magpies have been bred for being similarly loud and very good at mimicking sounds. So especially if it's a raven sized breed I don't see why this would be different from how people already use drones in RL.

Chickens can fly and have been domesticated already. Being ground nesting and ground feeding birds means they dislike flying, but they can still take to the air.

Swans have been relatively successful over the centuries, not that we eat them any more. You don't need to herd them as they come back to the same place each year to breed.
All you need is a system of marking who owns each one and a ritual rounding up of all the new cygnets and marking them according to who owns the parents, known as swan upping. This is done when the adults moult as they can't fly for a few weeks.
You have probably heard that the king owns all the swans, that's not actually true. The king only owns the swans that aren't owned by somebody else.

I see you mentioned passenger pigeons, but from what I know pigeons just in general would work. Many of the pigeons in populated cities actually are domesticated, just descended from abandoned ancestors. And while I've never personally eaten a pigeon, Dodoes were a member of the group and we all know how that went. Thus, I would advise pigeons, good work on your part. Hope this helped!

Something I forgot to mention- ever seen those pictures of pigeons with terrible nests? That's because they're the aforementioned feral, once-domesticated pigeons. Humans used to make their nests before pigeons fell out of fashion. Actually a rather interesting topic.

Is there any reason wood pigeons aren't strictly better than rock doves as livestock? If you start out with the wild version either way, then it seems like an enlarged cecum that allows more plant material to be digested is a big upside. Like our timeline has cereal agriculture, but if those aren't a major staple that seems to change the dynamic

Unfortunately, I lack the knowledge needed to answer this. I'm more a nerd with a lot of trivia than a ornithologist, so I've already stated about all I know about pigeons. If you can find another source though, that sounds like an interesting question. sorry for being useless here.

I remember being corrected in an earlier answer that squab is a normal part of some countries' diets.

@VakusDrake I could be wrong, but I think wood pigeons are territorial rather than gregarious. They certainly drive away their young once they're grown and it's time for a new batch, at least around here. Maybe it's driven by food availability.
